# Vue Test Utils - Cannot read property '$el' - $refs

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am trying to test a component that has a `VNavigationMenu` with a `$ref='drawer'` on it.
When I want to mount the component to a wrapper via `mount` and `shallowMount`, it throwns an error  `TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined` and points to a method of my component:

```js
setBorderWidth () {
  const i = this.$refs.drawer.$el.querySelector(
    '.v-navigation-drawer__border'
  )
  i.style.width = this.navigation.borderSize + 'px'
  i.style.cursor = 'ew-resize'
}
```

and here is the `VNavigationMenu` that's causing the problem:

```html
<v-navigation-drawer
  ref='drawer'
  v-model='drawer'
  :clipped='$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp'
  app
>
```

My test is below (error happens right when I want to mount the component):

```js
  test('mounting the component', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MainView, {
      localVue
    })
  })
```

My `mounted` hook:

```js
mounted: function () {
   this.setBorderWidth()
}
```

Comment: The cause can vary based on the context of the call. Can you show the relevant `mounted()` code that leads to `setBorderWidth()`?

Comment: @tony19 hey! i've added the mounted function to my post above, its just calling this.setBorderWidth()

Comment: Can you show more context around the `v-navigation-drawer`'s usage? Is the component conditionally rendered in `MainView`? If so, the `ref` won't necessarily exist in your test unless its rendering is toggled somehow.